# Visual Basic for Applications Query

Tags: excel, vba

I have one doubt here regarding how my code functions in Excel and what to know exactly why this is happening?

So I have two codes, I'll mention both below and provide the results on executing them.

**Code 1**

```
Sub ColorLoop()

    Dim red As Long
    Dim green As Long
    Dim blue As Long
    Dim c As Range

    red = Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(0, 255)
    blue = Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(0, 255)
    green = Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(0, 255)


    For Each c In selection
        c.Interior.Color = RGB(red, blue, green)
    Next c

End Sub
```

If I run code one, when I perform the selection in excel and run the macro the whole selection gets one random color.

**Code 2**

```
Sub ColorLoop()

    Dim red As Long
    Dim green As Long
    Dim blue As Long
    Dim c As Range

    For Each c In selection
        red = Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(0, 255)
        blue = Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(0, 255)
        green = Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(0, 255)

        c.Interior.Color = RGB(red, blue, green)
    Next c

End Sub
```

When I run code two and perform the selection , every cell in that selection has a different color

***I want to know why is this happening?***

Comment: In the first snippet, you're generating the colours once and applying them to every cell. In the second, you're generating different colours for every cell.

Comment: I don't get it. I have used the For Each Loop which should target each cell in the selection in both cases. Red, green and blue are just variables which should not affect.

Comment: But when are you setting/changing the value of those variables? In the first snippet you're changing the value once; and the value remains the same until the `Sub` exits. In the second snippet you're changing the value multiple times -- for each iteration of the `For Each` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As jsheenran pointed out, you only run the randomized colors once in the first snippet, while you run the randomized colors multiple times in the second snippet.

**Why Code 1 only generates one color:**

```
Sub ColorLoop()

    Dim red As Long
    Dim green As Long
    Dim blue As Long
    Dim c As Range

    red = Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(0, 255) ' Let's say the result=1
    blue = Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(0, 255)' Let's say the result=10
    green = Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(0, 255)'Let's say the result=20

' From here the red,blue, green are constant and every cell in the loop will have:

    For Each c In selection
        c.Interior.Color = RGB(1, 10, 20)
    Next c

End Sub
```